# iPhone calendar showing Chinese months

Tags: iphone, calendar, internationalization, language

Some things are in English and other are (I’m guessing) in Chinese.

How do I change my language settings to English.

[image]

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the status bar in the screenshot suggests it is from an iPhone X or 11, and the dark interface is new to iOS 13.

Comment: @Dillon Thanks. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have an alternate calendar turned on, in this case Chinese.

To turn this off:

1. Open the Settings app
2. Scroll down and tap Calendar
3. Tap Alternate Calendars
4. Tap Off

[image: Screenshot of Settings > Calendar > Alternate Calendars]

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese characters you see say "The twelfth lunar month", "twelfth lunar month" and "Chinese new year", as per Google Translate's app and camera.

I think you've subscribed to Chinese Holidays calendar. Tap the "! Calendars" button and see if it has something to remove. It shows a error sign anyway.